# Running code on Notepad++

Tags: java, notepad++

I am new to Notepad++ and cannot get it to run my program. here is my code:

```
public class Random {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        {   
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
            //Generates 10 random numbers
        for(int i = 0; i <numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*20 + 1);
        }//ends loop
        Sytem.out.println("Numbers Generated: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

        }       

    }

}
```

I have tried everything that I have come across online. This is the message that appears after I try to run my program:

```
>java assignment1
Process started >>>
Error: Could not find or load main class assignment1
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

Comment: My advice: Get IDE, save yourself this kind of frustration and don't listen to people that say you should learn to compile etc. using command line tools etc.. Because while it is true it may give you 1% better proficiency in "understanding how language works", but in the corporate  world that knowledge has zero added value for you. Since 99% of the time you will work with IDEs and it is valuable to learn your workflow in IDE from the start.

Comment: how are you running te program?

Comment: if you are a student, don't use IDE (its for learning purposes) . otherwise as @TheLaw said, definitely use IDE like Eclipse or Netbeams)

Comment: I ran my code using netbeans and it works just fine. But i have to use notepad++ and for some reason i just cant get anything to work with it.

Comment: Forget about running it in "Notepad++" and look at how to run it on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error you are receiving I believe it is because you're trying to compile "assignment1.java" and not "random.java". Class and file names must be the same.

Comment: They are executing java not javac, so they are attempting to run a class named assignment1, not compile a file in 'assignment1.java'.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is, but try to rename the file AND class to something not already in java like My_Random

Answer (score 1):

```
java assignment1 Process started
>>> Error: Could not find or load main class assignment1 <<< 
Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

> java assignment1

java - The executes a compiled version of your code. 
assignment1 - This is the application you are attempting to run. However you are currently working with `Random`.

Break out the command line and `cd` to where your code lives.

First you need to compile the software. In Java you use `javac` to do that, `javac` takes one param (that we care about right now), the name of the file you are attempting to compile.

`javac HelloWorld.java` for example would compile the code in a file called `HelloWorld.java`. Java requires the public class in a file to be named after the file it is in. So the class `Random` should be in a file named `Random.java`.

Once we have compiled it we need to run it. We can do this with the command `java`. This takes one param (that we care about right now), the name of the class you want to execute. If we have a class called `HelloWorld` then we would execute

`java HelloWorld`  - Notice the lack of `.java` or `.class`.

You code above creates a class called `Random`.